# Get text from URL

Tags: java, html, proxy, jsoup

I'm trying to get all the text of an URL using Jsoup, this is the code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(Url).get();
System.out.println(doc.text());
```

But the problem is that this is not working fine for all the URL's I tried...
I need to get all the text from the web page (parsing the HTML) because I'm implementing a proxy using sockets and I need to connect to a URL, then find the selected word and if it exists I need to block the mentioned URL, if it does not exists then the web page is returned to the browser.

There's any other way to get all the text from the web page?

Thanks!

Comment: `problem is that this is not working fine for all the URL's I tried...` how exactly is it not working? Can you give some examples of input, actual output and expected output?

Comment: how about not using Jsoup at all and try something like this: 
      URL url = new URL(args[0]);
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(url.openStream());
      while (scan.hasNextLine())
         //use the document api to insert strings into it
}

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood properly, you want all the text from a web page, right? This code should get all the texts from the web page.

```
  import org.jsoup.*;
  import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
  import org.jsoup.select.*;

  public class Getdata {
    public Getdata() {
      try {
           String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597755/get-text-from-url";
           Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
           Elements element = doc.select("p");

           for (Element t : element) {
             System.out.println(t.text());
           }

         } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.err.println(ex);

      }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Getdata();

 }
   }
```

Thanks.